# function doesn't return, very weird

Tags: ruby, calabash-android

I have a function which gets an array of element, then it iterates over the array, when expected element is found it breaks and return.

The function is this:

```
def get_expected_element(id:, name:)
  # I am sure there are 3 elements got
  elem_array = get_all_elements(id)

  element = nil
  elem_array.each { |elem|
    # I see this log
    puts "elem = #{elem}"

    if elem == name
      element = elem
      # I see this log too
      puts "Found element"
      break
    end
  }
  # I see this log too, and program is hanging
  puts "=== return ==="
  element
end
```

When I invoke the function, the program is hanging after `puts "=== return ==="`:

```
service = MyService.new
element_got = service.get_expected_element(id:3, name:"apple")

# I don't see the below log
puts "#{element_got}, I don't see this, why?"
```

The log in console is this:

```
elem = orange
elem = apple
Found element
=== return ===

<it is hanging>
```

I cannot understand why the invoked function doesn't return?

Comment: Have you tried an explicit return statement? (i.e. return element). I don't understand why that might make a difference but its something easy to try at first.

Comment: Yes, tried, same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out MyService I ran this:

```
def get_expected_element(id:, name:)
  # I am sure there are 3 elements got
  # elem_array = get_all_elements(id)
  elem_array = ["elem1", "apple", "elem3"]

  element = nil
  elem_array.each { |elem|
    # I see this log
    puts "elem = #{elem}"

    if elem == name
      element = elem
      # I see this log too
      puts "Found element"
      break
    end
  }
  # I see this log too, and program is hanging
  puts "=== return ==="
  element
end

puts get_expected_element(id: 3, name: "apple")
```

and got this:

```
elem = elem1
elem = apple
Found element
=== return ===
apple
```

Your get_expected_element method seems fine.